# How to get rid of the App Drawer/App Store button in Messages?

Tags: messages, ios

I recently updated my phone to iOS 11 and I find the new "App Drawer" at the bottom of my messages to be annoying. I saw on [gadgethacks.com](https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/remove-bottom-app-drawer-ios-11s-messages-app-for-iphone-0180129/) that if you click on the App Store button it hides the App Drawer. However, if I click the App Store button again and exit out of my message and return to it, the App Drawer reappears in all its glory.

I want to know if there is any way to permanently remove the App Drawer/App Store button from Messages?

Comment: I've read, like you've experienced, that it comes back again after tapping on the App Store button.  I've also seen some people say do tap on it again after it comes back and then it stays away 'for a while'.  I don't know how long 'a while' is.